# Append text to form input element value on focusout()

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'd like to append a 'saved' text to a value in an input form element when it goes out of focus. I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

My element:

```
<div class="info small">
   <span class="element">
        <label for="email">Email</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="email" value="" />
   </span>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('div.info').on('keyup', 'input', function(event){
    $id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    $id = parseInt($id);
    $field = $(this).attr('id');
    $text = $(this).val();
    updateField($id, $field, $text);
});

$('div.info').on('focusout', 'input', function(event){
    $('input').append(' saved.');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can gather, you'd like the input to have the given value plus ' saved.':

```
$('div.info').on('focusout', 'input', function(event){
    $(this).val(this.value + " saved.");
});
```

Of course it will append it multiple times, if you focus out of the input multiple times, but I'll leave that issue for you to have a go at.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUzux/1/)

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I wanted. You're right about the last point, obviously, but that should be easy to solve with a condition. Cheers.

Comment: It sure will, glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 3):

Use `.blur()` and set the `val` of the input:

```
$('div.info').on('blur', 'input', function(event){
    var currentVal = this.value;
    $('.input').val(currentVal + ' saved.');
});
```

Comment: That works, yes, but I don't want it to change the element's value completely. I want to append it to the value that was input by the user if that's at all possible.

Comment: @vanamerongen -- Updated my answer to accomodate.

Comment: Ah yes, this also works. I'm gonna have to look up what the difference is between blur() and focusout()